# How to return from nested function in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm wrapping my dynamoDB function into another function and I'm having issues with returning it to the "item" const. What I'm missing here?

Works:

```
    const params = {
      TableName: table,
      Key: {
        id: id
      },
    };

    dynamoDb.get(params, (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        callback(null, {
          statusCode: error.statusCode || 501,
          body: 'Couldn\'t fetch the item.',
        });
        return;
      }

      const item = result.Item
    })
```

Doesn't work (returns undefinied):

```
  const getFromDb = () => {
    const params = {
      TableName: table,
      Key: {
        id: id
      },
    };

    dynamoDb.get(params, (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        callback(null, {
          statusCode: error.statusCode || 501,
          body: 'Couldn\'t fetch the item.',
        });
        return;
      }

      return result.Item
    })
  }

  // Get from db
  const item = getFromDb()
  // do stuff with result item...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What currently happens in your code is `getFromDb` function will run `dynamoDb.get(...)` and immediately return (undefined in your case, because there is no return statement inside `getFromDb`). By the time `getFromDb` returns, your dynamoDb request hasn't even resolved yet, it will resolve at some point in the future and call the callback you provided `(error, result) => { ... }`

To achieve what you described, you need to:

1. make `getFromDb` return [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which will only resolve after your request resolves
2. `await` for that function when calling it, getting result into which your Promise resolves (or and error if it rejects)

.

```
// marking this function async is not required but good to have
// to not forget that this function returns a promise, not immediate result
const getFromDb = async () => {
  // wrapped body in a promise
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const params = {
      TableName: table,
      Key: {
        id: id
      },
    }

    dynamoDb.get(params, (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        // in case of error, we reject promise with that error
        reject(error)
        return
      }
      // otherwise, we resolve with result
      resolve(result.Item)
    })
  })
}

// usage with async/await
// I wrapped significant code in asynchronous function f and then called it
// just to emphasize that you can only use async/await inside async function
// if you are already in async function, you don't need to do this
const f = async () => {
  try {
    const item = await getFromDb();
    console.log(item)
  } catch(error) {
    // the error we rejected with
    console.error(error)
  }
}

f()


// alternative way without async/await, using Promise chaining
getFromDb()
  .then(item => console.log(item))
  .catch(error => console.error(error))
```